# Magento. O conteúdo do CMS está bloqueado

Tags: magento

Quando entro no painel do Magento (CMS>Pages), e entro em uma das página já existentes, não consigo abrir o Page Information e o Content. Além disso, não consigo criar nenhuma página.

Como faço para desbloquear isso?

Answer (score 0):

Existe alguma informação de erro na página ou no console do navegador? Instalaram algum módulo recentemente?

Caso tenha sido instalado algum módulo, peço que crie um ambiente de testes por segurança se ainda não houver um, e desabilite o módulo instalado para verificar se as funcionalidades normalizam, pois pode ser algum conflito. Lembrando que para desativar um módulo completamente, a melhor forma é indo em app/etc/modules/nomedomodulo.xml e renomeando o xml. Exemplo: nomedomodulo.xml.disabled

Caso não seja isso, nos dê mais informações para que possamos lhe ajudar ;)